# WiFiAdapter.ConnectAsync does not work under remote desktop

Tags: .net, wifi, remote-desktop

On a c# .net application I use the following code in order to connect to a WiFI AP.

```
private async Task<bool> Connect(WiFiAvailableNetwork network, String password)
{
    WiFiReconnectionKind reconnectionKind = WiFiReconnectionKind.Automatic;
    WiFiConnectionResult result = null;

    if (network.SecuritySettings.NetworkAuthenticationType == NetworkAuthenticationType.Open80211)
    {
        result = await wifiAdapter.ConnectAsync(network, reconnectionKind);
    }
    else
    {
        var credential = new PasswordCredential();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            credential.Password = password;
        }
        
        result = await wifiAdapter.ConnectAsync(network, reconnectionKind, credential).AsTask();
    }

    return (result.ConnectionStatus == WiFiConnectionStatus.Success);
}
```

When working on the PC which runs this code there is no problem.
When connected to the PC via remote desktop (with a wired LAN connection), I can connect to the AP only in the first 5/10 minutes, after that the ConnectAsync always returns NetworkNotAvailable. In this case, in order to connect again to my AP I can only reboot the PC, Logging off and on, or closing the remote desktop and connecting with direct access to the PC.

When the ConnectAsync returns NetworkNotAvailable, I can connect to the AP using the windows interface, even when I am connected to the PC via remote desktop. What I noticed is that the connection through the Windows interface is much slower than the wifiAdapter.Connect.